# References show on Overleaf but not locally

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, bibunits

I have the following code (all the packages are provided by default so I don't want to remove any of them):

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn,showpacs,superscriptaddress,prl,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}

\newcommand{\revtex}{REV\TeX\ }
\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\linespread{2}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\newbibstartnumber}[1]{%
  \apptocmd{\thebibliography}{%
    \global\c@NAT@ctr #1\relax
    \addtocounter{NAT@ctr}{-1}%
  }{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{\huge Title title}

\maketitle
\date{}
\begin{bibunit}[unsrt]
 
\onecolumngrid

Something something \cite{tanabashi2018review} something.

\putbib[references_main]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

The reference I am citing is this one:

```
@article{tanabashi2018review,
  title={{Review of Particle Physics: particle data groups}},
  author={Tanabashi, M. and others},
  journal={Physical Review D},
  volume={98},
  number={3},
  pages={1--1898},
  year={(2018)}
}
```

and it is located in a file called `references_main.bib` (located in the same folder as the main.tex file). If I run this on Overleaf, I get the right output (the reference appears as [1]). However if I run it locally, I get [?]. By running it locally I mean running this on my terminal (on Mac):

```
latex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

I tried running each command more than once, also trying several `bibtex main` in between, but nothing seems to be working. What do I need to do? Thank you!

Comment: Don't run `latex` and `pdflatex`. You should use one or the other unless you want both DVI and PDF output. Regardless of whether somebody gave you a template with all these packages in the preamble, your preamble will cause you grief if you do not tame it. Load `hyperref` **last** and **only once**. You are also loading other things e.g. `dcolumn` twice.

Comment: You need to run `bibtex` on the unit files e.g. `bibtex bu1` and `bibtex bu2`. You should have one run of `bibtex` for each unit and probably another if you have a global bibliography, too.

Comment: Why are you loading `lipsum`? It's sole purpose is to produce filler text (in Latin) for examples, but you don't use it here. `epstopdf` is unnecessary unless you're using really ancient software.

Comment: @cfr running only latex or pdflatex doesn't work either. what is bu1 and bu2 in this example?

Comment: Those are the files you need to run `bibtex` on. That's what `bibunits` does. It sends your citation information to separate files (one per unit). Then you process each one with `bibtex` to produce a bilbiography for that unit. I didn't say running only one of `latex` or `pdflatex` would fix this problem. For that, you need to run `bibtex` * times on the relevant files and recompile. I just said running both was pointless unless you want both DVI and PDF output.

Comment: Note that I don't remember if I've ever used `bibunits`. I'm just reading the documentation. Overleaf does this for you. For a local TeX install, you have to run the commands (or arrange to have them run) yourself. `texdoc bibunits` for the documentation. Do you have any files `bu` *n* `.` *<ext>* in your document directory, where *n* is an integer and *<ext>* is a likely-looking extension? (`aux` I think.)

Comment: you need to run bibtex, if you want a system like overleaf that runs pdflatex and bibtex automatically as needed use latexmk that is what they use

Comment: What @DavidCarlisle said. Technical details can be seen at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F